# What encoding should i set in Android Studio class to be correct in output

Tags: selenium, android-studio, xpath, appium

I'm facing some weird problem with encoding in Android Studio. I moved my project from Eclipse, and now strings that i need to find using xpath, are different.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Zakładki']")).click();
```

and what actually has been used by Selenium and Appium server:

> utf-8: 
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.TextView[@text='ZakÅadki']}
>
> windows-1250: *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Zak³adki']}
>
> ISO-8859-1*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Zak?adki']}

any suggestions how to resolve this problem?

Comment: convert file encoding to UTF-8

Comment: @Abhishek_Mishra, i did it and word 'Zakładki' is then sent as 'ZakÅadki'